# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation with $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, ajaxform

I know this get asked a lot, but I am at the end of my rope on this one trying to figure out why and understand why this error is occurring.

I have a form that is supposed to submit with ajax, but I keep getting an Illegal invocation error whenever I try to put the ajax in. Its a modification of an existing code.

```
var Login = function () {

var handleLogin = function() {

    $('.login-form').validate({

        ...other functions here to do with validation...

         submitHandler: function (form) {
                formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "includes/processors/login.php",
                    data: formData,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result) {
                        $.each(result, function(item, value){
                            if(item == 'Success'){
                                window.location.replace("index.php");
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        var returnMes = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                        $('.alert-danger').text(returnMes);
                        $('.alert-danger').show();
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });

        $('.login-form input').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                if ($('.login-form').validate().form()) {
                    //$('.login-form').submit();//form validation success, call ajax form submit
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you need to serialize this `formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);` you are returning an object and not a plain string to be submitted with ajax

Comment: So am i better off doing formData = $('.login-form').seralize(); rather than using FormData?

Comment: you can pass the values one by one in json format